# Bootstrap container-fluid padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following HTML is generating unwanted padding:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshot showing the problem:**

[image: Screenshot showing the problem]

Comment: That is the bootstrap padding, when you use class "container" there is a padding, and when you use "col" there is a padding too. The only way to remove the padding its from bootstrap.css

Comment: @Francisco Fernandez Yes. I'm thinking about remove this padding from bootstrap.css but as far as I remember formerly this work correctly.

Answer (score 55):

None of the answers here helped me with Bootstrap 4.

Adding `container-fluid p-0` removed the horizontal padding, but created a horizontal scrollbar.

The scrollbars come from the negative margin of the row elements - a 100% width container with no padding gets stretched by 15px on each side. It has nothing to do with column padding, as far as I can see.

The only workaround for me was

`.container-fluid{
overflow: hidden;
}`

Comment: As an improvement of this answer, you can easily remove padding and avoid the horizontal scrollbar simply adding the `no-gutters`  class to the `row` element. This removes the negative margins as stated by the official documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters. So, no further css rules are needed.

Comment: @wiredolphin This also removes `the horizontal padding from all immediate children columns`.

Comment: that answer can help you! 2019 :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978307/bootstrap-container-fluid-padding/56655968#56655968

Answer (score 30):

Just add class p-0 to class container-fluid & then add class no-gutters to child elements of class row, if you have more than one add to all rows.

Example:

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Or
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is right solution for case when you have only 1 column

Comment: this should really be the accepted answer. Don't forget that if you embed row you should add the `no-gutters` class to those as well.

Answer (score 17):

2019 correct way according to the docs is using "x" in your `p-0` class. 
When you use `p-0` you are setting padding for top, right, bottom and left. If you use `px-0` it's for left-and-right "X coordinates" and so if you set `py-0` it's "Y coordinates and at the `<div class="row no-gutters">..`.

Should be like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
 <div class="row no-gutters">
     [..... other codes]
 </div>
</div>
```

Take a look into the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/#notation

Comment: I went back to a legacy project where I still need to use Bootstrap, and if you want gutters between your columns, this won't work. It seems that in 2020, there's no official solution to creating a full width grid with no weird container padding or missing column gutter.

Answer (score 8):

Adding these classes helped me

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0 overflow-hidden">
```

Comment: That's the correct way to do it when you have several columns and you want gutters only on the inside but not on the sides, as when you want side columns to reach the edge of the window. It's ugly, but it works.

Comment: literally the only answer that actually works today in 2023

Answer (score 5):

Just add this css

```
.container-fluid {
   padding: 0px;
}
```

[Your Code with this CSS](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEOjWp)

EDIT:

With this all the page going to have 0 padding. If you only want 0 padding in that part of the page maybe you should create a class "container-0padding" with that css code for example.

Comment: Yes, I did it that way but I'm a little bit confused why this padding exist when I'm using container-fluid :D

Comment: Because this: .container-fluid {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
} 
That is the code from bootstrap.css

Comment: and then we have .row {margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;}

Comment: This generates horizontal scroll using Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the column is actually causing the padding, which is written into the bootstrap .css file.

You didn't mention what version of Bootstrap you're using, I assume 3.x?

I usually add a custom class to my own .css file to eliminate padding when it's not wanted, such as:

```
.noPadding {
padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Then add the class to your column like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 noPadding">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-grid-system/) helped me understand the basics of the Bootstrap grid system and how it handles margins and padding.

Bootstrap 4 will include padding and utility classes to manipulate padding more precisely. 
[Read about it here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/#spacing)

Comment: Bootstrap 4 beta ist out. Indeed you won't need an custom classes, just use `<div class="container-fluid p-0">`. The docs are here now: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: @amoebe This should be the accepted answer. I did this but my page now has a horizontal scrollbar. Any fixes with that or is one of my elements just too large?

Comment: @cjones3724 Sounds like you have at least one element in your row with a fixed width.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a solution that doesn't involve CSS hacks - Just wrap you current row in another row

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">    
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you look at what row does:

```
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
```

So ading another row will just offset the padding created by your `<div class="col-xs-12">`

Answer (score 2):

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 p-0">
        test
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The solution can be achieved by this when you give p-0 to the inner column or you can add a class with the column like "xyz" and give it styling to
".xyz{padding: 0!important;}"

Answer (score 2):

For Bootstrap 5 and possibly others, you're overthinking it. You do not need container-fluid in order for your Grid to work properly. From the documentation: "Need an edge-to-edge design? Drop the parent .container or .container-fluid." See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/

So here I just added a 100% width for demonstration.

```
<div style="width: 100%">
    <div class="row g-0">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for Bootstrap 3

```
.container {
   width: calc(100% + 30px);
   padding-right: 0;
   padding-left: 0;
   margin-left: -30px;
   overflow: hidden;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In 2023 and bootstrap 5+ this still doesn't seem like it's actually supported. A bunch of answers here are saying to drop the gutters, but that's not what most people actually want. In most cases you just want the top level app/parent container to be 100% width (with NO extra 15px padding on each side), and then the children to work as a normal bootstrap grid with normal gutters.

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0 overflow-hidden">
```

this is the only thing that accomplishes this today. it feels somehow.. wrong to set overflow to hidden but I don't see any real downside besides just looking at it to make sure nothing is overflowing and cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I think those padding is a result with your styling. check the CSS section/file. or post the full code here. then we will be able to give a solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think It works well.

```
<section class="your-class">
    <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```css
.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 has .p-0 for that

Comment: Right you're Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap5, *"container-fluid"* can't use External CSS.
So just *write* as,

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 3% 12%;">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me just adding the row class does the trick

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this one in 2023. If you are using Bootstrap 5 and SASS to compile your css you can use the custom container mixin.

Within your scss file:

```
@import "../bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints.scss";
@mixin make-container($padding-x: $container-padding-x) {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: $padding-x;
    padding-left: $padding-x;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
// Usage
.container-max {  
   @include make-container(0);
}
```

Then within your html:

```
<div class=" container-max ">
    <div class="row g-0">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/#sass and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#sass

Answer (score -1):

Like Jake, I think there is no sense to use 12 columns inside container fluid. Fluid is intended to use 100% width. When you set container-fluid class bootstrap adds padding, and when you set class row, bootstrap adds negative margin, so content goes full width.

Answer (score -4):

Just remove `.col-xs-12`. It makes no sense to wrap your content in full-width column additionally.