# Make a bootstrap 4 container-fluid go full bleed to edge of browser window

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 and I'm trying to get a bootrap container and its content to go full width and bleed all the way to the view port.

My initial solution added padding off the side of the screen which lead to the window scrolling right 15px.

My second partial solution is based on this answer for bootstrap 3: [Bootstrap container-fluid padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978307/bootstrap-container-fluid-padding/50005919)

With this approach I get the bleed to the left of the screen, but 30px gap remains on the right. I can't see what I should have done to get the full width container working.

Here's code that fully represents the problem. The content that I want to go to the edge of screen happens to be a map. I doubt that's relevant, but have included in case:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var map
        var geocoder

        function initMap() {
            // received letters array

            // create map object
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 3,
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
            })

            var userLocation = "London"
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
            geocoder.geocode({'address': "London"}, function(results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                } else {
                    console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status)
                }
            })


            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap)
        }
        </script>

        <style>
            .container-fluid.full-width {
                padding:0px;
            }

            .change-margins {
                margin-left:-15px;
                margin-right:-15px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body style="background-color:blue;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          nav     
        </nav>

        <div id="content" class="container-fluid full-width">

            <div id="map-panel" class="container-fluid change-margins">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 m-2">
                                <h1>Title</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <style>
                            /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
                            * element that contains the map. */
                            #map {
                                height: 100%;
                                min-height: 300px;
                            }
                            /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
                            html, body {
                                height: 100%;
                                margin: 0;
                                padding: 0;
                            }
                        </style>

                        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={api-key}=initMap"></script>

                        <div id="map">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <h1>Content below map</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What should I have done in order to get the content to meet the edge of the browser window?

Comment: Add class name ".full-width" to the parent div .  Eg: "container-fluid full-width"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5** - update 2021

The `.no-gutters` class has been replaced with `.g-0`. Use it the .row where you want no spacing, and `.p-0` on the container for an edge-to-edge width.

**Bootstrap 4** - original question.

Because Bootstrap's grid row has negative margins, removing padding from the the container alone won't work. You also shouldn't have nested containers.

**To make a full width layout (no extra CSS)...**

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col">
            (edge to edge content...)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Therefore, for your layout..

1. remove the padding on the container-fluid using `px-0`
2. remove the negative margins on the row using `no-gutters`:

https://codeply.com/p/5ihF13YSBL

Also, since you're using only 1 grid column, you can simply zero out the padding on it using `px-0`.

---

To remove the spacing between columns (gutter) [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254889/bootstrap-remove-the-gutter-spacing-between-columns/21256143#21256143)

Comment: Thanks for this. I knew I was barking up the wrong tree. Frustratingly this has revealed that the 15px scroll to the right is actually being caused by the map itself. But at least I've successfully isolated the problem.

Comment: Found my error now, just needed to add no-gutters to nested rows, not just the top one in my example code. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. You need to add one more class "full-width" to the "container-fluid" class name.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map
    var geocoder

    function initMap() {
        // received letters array

        // create map object
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 3,
            mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        })

        var userLocation = "London"
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
        geocoder.geocode({'address': "London"}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            } else {
                console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status)
            }
        })


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap)
    }
    </script>

    <style>
        .container-fluid.full-width {
            padding:0px;
        }

        .change-margins {
            margin-left:-15px;
            margin-right:-15px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body style="background-color:blue;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      nav     
    </nav>

    <div id="content" class="container-fluid full-width">

        <div id="map-panel" class="container-fluid change-margins">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 m-2">
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <style>
                        /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
                        * element that contains the map. */
                        #map {
                            height: 100%;
                            min-height: 300px;
                        }
                        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
                        html, body {
                            height: 100%;
                            margin: 0;
                            padding: 0;
                        }
                    </style>

                    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={api-key}=initMap"></script>

                    <div id="map">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid full-width">
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <h1>Content below map</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Anish - was that additional full-width on the bottom container-fluid div? Oddly it's not working for me. I copied your body tag in full and I still get 30px gap between right hand side of map and browser window.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="map-panel" class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 p-0">
        <h1> Title </h1>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no need to do extra things just give p-0 class to col-12 which add padding: 0!important