# On my web page, there is free space on the left, and right. How to get rid of it?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Firstly i tried to do margin:0, and padding:0 for body element. But it didn't work. I inspected it to see what's going on google developer tools. I saw my .container-fluid class which has some bootstrap properties by default, has padding in left, and right. So when i write in developer tools; .container-fluid{ padding:0} it works, it deletes that free space. But when I do it in my css file, it doesn't work. Since I didn't want to use !important keyword, cause I think It must have worked...So  I need your help, what's my mistake? Thanks.

```css
.container-fluid {
    padding: 0; 
}
.title-image {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Python Bootcamp Web Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>


    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <section >
        <div class="container-fluid">
<!--all of element appeared when i wrote navbar-expand-lg-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-info">        
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-python"> Python Bootcamp</i>
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Courses</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">How We Work</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Outcomes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
            </nav>

            <!-- Title -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6"> <!-- so it will fill 50% of width on screen of laptops, and bigger screens-->
                    <h1>Download the best bootcamp, and start to study now.</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-light"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img class="title-image" src="image.jpg" alt="classroom-image">
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the `navbar` out of the container...

```
<section>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-info">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-python"> Python Bootcamp</i>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Courses</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">How We Work</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Outcomes</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!--all of element appeared when i wrote navbar-expand-lg-->
        <!-- Title -->
        <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <!-- so it will fill 50% of width on screen of laptops, and bigger screens-->
                <h1>Download the best bootcamp, and start to study now.</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-light"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img class="title-image" src="image.jpg" alt="classroom-image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/Eb50NfIHfJ)

If you also want to remove left/right space from the content area, use `p-0` on the container, and `g-0` (no-gutters) on the row (otherwise you'll get undesired horizontal scrolling).

Also see: [Make a bootstrap 4 container-fluid go full bleed to edge of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100707/make-a-bootstrap-4-container-fluid-go-full-bleed-to-edge-of-browser-window)

Comment: Just adding body .container-fluid{ padding:0;} worked with no problem, if im not wrong.

Comment: You get a horizontal scroll bar

Comment: Well I did it on purpose, I have horizontal bar because I added navbar-expand-lg in my nav class. You said that? or something I have mistake?

Comment: I mean the browsers horizontal scroll bar, not the navbar

Answer (score -1):

In this case, it might be best to just use `!important`. Or, if you really don't want to, you can make the selector more specific (and thus more "important" that the bootstrap one) by prepending `body` to it. For example:

```css
body .container-fluid {
    padding: 0; 
}
.title-image {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Python Bootcamp Web Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>


    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <section >
        <div class="container-fluid">
<!--all of element appeared when i wrote navbar-expand-lg-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-info">        
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-python"> Python Bootcamp</i>
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Courses</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">How We Work</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Outcomes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
            </nav>

            <!-- Title -->
            <div class="row g-0">
                <div class="col-lg-6"> <!-- so it will fill 50% of width on screen of laptops, and bigger screens-->
                    <h1>Download the best bootcamp, and start to study now.</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-light"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img class="title-image" src="image.jpg" alt="classroom-image">
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>    
</body>
</html>
```

Note that to prevent horizontal scrolling, I also had to add a `.g-0` class to the `.row` element.

Comment: This causes a horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Thanks @JacobLockard, being more specific like body. container-fluid , worked. I didn't think it would work since i still say its a class, not id or not like other specific selectors. Thank you again. But I didnt understand why you added g-0 class. What did it change?

Comment: @Semih The reason that `body .container-fluid` is more specific than just `.container-fluid` is because the *number* of selector types also affects [selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59104325/4713952) explains the necessity of the `g-0` class. Essentially, it prevents the `.row` element from expanding beyond the container, causing an unwanted horizontal scrollbar.